# Magento 2 - Controller with parameter

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, controllers, parameter

I want to create the controller which get the parameter like

```
http://example.com/manufacturerpages/index/id/497
```

When I do this, It goes to 404 error plus I am also not able to get the id in controller by using this code

```
$mId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
```

I don't need the solution like

```
http://example.com/manufacturerpages/index?id/497
```

Because I have to use it in URL Rewrite so in that case, it is not working

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated.

Comment: you should create your own route fro that to work

Comment: I already know that, what I need to know that how we do that?  If you have the relevant example or experience then share it on answer

Comment: okay but using custom route. I will post below

Comment: ok but don't post the general addition of custom route which I can easily access from google. It must have the part of parameter addition and use it on controller (relevant)

Comment: I'm talking about this `http://example.com/manufacturerpages/index/custom/route/id/497`

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92991/discussion-between-magefms-and-muhammad-hasham).

Comment: deleted my answer as it gets over killed by downvotes. I posted it as per muhammad hasham. I just shared what works for me. you guys are the best of all.

Comment: @magefms I always appreciate relevant knowledge sharing by upvoting  as you already know because you also posted an answer before on my other posts as well. I don't know why there is too much downvote but to be very honest, Answer is not up to the mark and relevant. So never mind, keep coding thanks :)

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Yes I found the solution and working on it, After I finished, I will surely post it here

Comment: Muhammad Hasham Can you share solution please? I want to try it as well. Thanks

Comment: @magefms added solution for you and others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I worked on it, got the solution. First you need the create the `di.xml` to your module. As it is frontend custom router so you have to define it in `etc\frontend`. Type name for Router list addition is `Magento\Framework\App\RouterList`

Path should be like: `app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customRouteForBlog" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Naheed\Manufacturerpages\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then you need to add the `Router.php` in your module file

Path should be like: `app\code\Vendor\Module\Controller\Router.php`. You need to define `match` function in your router file after than you can forward the request from wherever you want

```
class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    public function  match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) {
    }
}
```

As my work belongs to `URL Rewrite`. So I made a new URL Rewrite and define request path and target path for that. So when user hit the request it come on the match function then you will redirect it to request path

**I hope this will help**

Answer (score 1):

You can try by below method. Queries will be passed after appending **?**.

```
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

UrlInterface $urlBuilder

$this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;

$queryParams = [
    'oid' => base64_encode($data['order_id']),
    'cid' => base64_encode($data['customer_id'])
];

$this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('controller/index', ['_current' => true,'_use_rewrite' => true, '_query' => $queryParams]);
```

Comment: I don't get it, did you read my question completely? just asking, because I think you gave me answer to something else. I already solved this problem and shared the answer as well. Still thanks for your answer.

Comment: For your effort and time +1.